# Bounded resolvent

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I am finding a somewhat obscure wording on my functional analysis text. $A$ is a linear operator *on* a complex Banach space $E$, which I'm almost sure to mean that $A$ is $E\to E$. Then I read that if the operator $R_\lambda=(A-\lambda I)^{-1}$ is defined on all of $E$, then it is bounded. I suspect that the condition that $A$ is **bounded** is required, because [theorem 2 here](http://books.google.it/books?id=cbbCAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA229#v=onepage&q&f=false) would -I think- guarantee that. Is that so?

$\infty$ thanks!

Comment: I think you are right. Assuming it is well defined, $R_{\lambda}$ is bounded if and only if $A$ is bounded.

Comment: @Crostul Only if $A$ is globally defined. Generally, for an operator $A$ whose domain is a subspace of $E$, the condition is that $A$ be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your link doesn't work for me (page unavailable or reached limit for viewing). But, if $D\subset E$ is a subspace, and $A\colon D\to E$ linear such that $A-\lambda I \colon D\to E$ is bijective [that is, $R_\lambda = (A-\lambda I)^{-1}$ is defined on all of $E$], then

- $R_\lambda$ is bounded if and only if $A$ is closed.

For, $R_\lambda$ is a globally defined linear operator on a Banach space, hence by the closed graph theorem, $R_\lambda$ is bounded if and only if it is continuous if and only if its graph is closed. But the graph of $R_\lambda$ is just the flipped graph of $A-\lambda I$, so $R_\lambda$ is bounded if and only if $A-\lambda I$ is closed. But $A-\lambda I$ is closed if and only if $A$ is closed. If $D = E$, then being closed and being bounded (continuous) are the same for $A$.

Comment: As to opening Googlebooks pages, I've noticed that reloading the page often makes it available. In any case, if it's said that "$A$ is an operator on $E$", does it mean that it's $A:E\to E$ (mapping all of $E$ into itself)? Thank you so much again!

Comment: Thanks for the tip with the Googlebooks, I'll try that next time if I don't forget. Unfortunately, there is no universal terminology concerning the distinction between $A\colon D\to E$ where $D = E$ or merely $D\subset E$. Using "on" rather than "in" can indicate that only globally defined operators are meant, but it need not. The only sure way is to explicitly say the operators shall be globally defined/defined on all of $E$/other unambiguous phrasings. Or to explain the terminology one uses at the beginning of the chapter/section.